# What is the series for $\frac{e^x -1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, power-series, taylor-expansion

There is a question in my Calc review packet that says the following:

29. Use series to approximate the integral of $(e^x − 1)/x$ from $0$ to $1$.  (Write out $4$ terms but do not add them.)

The answer given is:
$S4 = 1 +
1/4
+
1/24
+
1/96$

How would you write the series for $(e^x - 1)/x$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) is a MathJax tutorial.  How would you write the series for $e^x$?

Comment: and did you mean $18$ where you wrote $24$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Ha!  I was just about to ask that.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I got a series using the series for e^x, but my answer did not match up with the answer key, so I was confused because I actually did get 1/18 for my third term! I guess it must have been a mistake on the answer key, since you also got 1/18. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

**Basic approach.** Take the following steps:

- Write out the Taylor series for $e^x$
- Subtract $1$ from the previous result
- Divide the previous result by $x$
- Take just the first four terms of the above, yielding a cubic polynomial
- Integrate this polynomial from $x = 0$ to $1$

Answer (score 0):

$$e^x=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}+\dots$$

$$e^x-1=x+\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{x^4}{24}+\dots$$

$$\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1+\dfrac x2+\dfrac{x^2}6+\dfrac{x^3}{24}+\dots$$

$$\int _0^1\dfrac{e^x-1}x dx=x+\dfrac {x^2}4+\dfrac{x^3}{\color{red}{18}}+\dfrac{x^4}{96}+\dots\large\mid_0^1$$

$$=1+\dfrac14+\dfrac1{\color{red}{18}}+\dfrac1{96}+\dots$$

There must have been a mistake in the answer key.

Answer (score 0):

$(e^t-1)/t=1/(\sum_{k\ge0}B_m^-t^m/m!)$, where the $B_m^-$ are Bernoulli numbers.